# Prove that there is a $\delta$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^2dx\leq \delta$$\int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^2dx$ for all $f$ with these conditions

Tags: analysis, integration, contest-math

Let $S=\{f:\mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}\}$ that satisfies:
$\forall f\in S$, $f'$ exists and $f'$ is continuous
and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Please prove that $\exists \delta :\forall f\in S$ s.t. 
$\int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^2dx\leq \delta \int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^2dx$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to prove that there is an $m>0$ such that
$$
J(u)\ge m \quad \forall\ u \in H_0^1(0,1),\  \|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}=1,
$$
where the functional $J$ is defined by
$$
J: H_0^1(0,1) \to [0,\infty),\ J(u)=\|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2.
$$
For every $u \in H_0^1(0,1)$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1u^2(x)\,dx&=&\int_0^1\Big(\int_0^xu'(t)\,dt\Big)^2\,dx\le\int_0^1\Big(\int_0^x|u'(t)|\,dt\Big)^2\,dx\\
&\le&\int_0^1x\int_0^x(u'(t))^2\,dt\,dx\le\int_0^1x\int_0^1(u'(t))^2\,dt\,dx=\frac12\int_0^1(u'(x))^2\,dx.
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that 
$$
J(u) \ge 2 \quad \forall\ u \in H_0^1(0,1), \|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}=1,
$$
i.e. $J$ is bounded below on $M=\{u \in H_0^1(0,1):\ \|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2=1\}$.

So, let
$$
m=\inf_MJ.
$$
If there is a $u \in M$ such that $J(u)=m$, then by the Lagrange multipliers rule there exists some scalar $\lambda$ such that
$$
\int_0^1u'\phi'=\lambda\int_0^1u\phi \quad \forall\ \phi \in C_0^1(0,1),
$$
i.e. $\lambda$ and $u$ solve the problem
$$\tag{1}
u''+\lambda u=0 \ \text{ in } (0,1), \ u(0)=0=u(1).
$$
Solving (1) we get
$$
u(x)=u_\lambda(x)=a\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x),\ \lambda \in \{k^2\pi^2:\ k \in \mathbb{N}\},\ a\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Hence $m=\pi^2$, i.e.
$$
\int_0^1u^2(x)\,dx\le \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^1(u')^2(x)\,dx \quad \forall u \in  H_0^1(0,1).
$$
**Another approach** is to use Fourier analysis. Since $\phi_k(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(k\pi x), k \in \mathbb{N}$ form a basis for $H_0^1(0,1)$, any $u \in H_0^1(0,1)$ can be written as
$$
u=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(u)\phi_k,\ a_k(u)=\int_0^1u(x)\phi_k(x)\,dx.
$$
Hence, for every $u \in H_0^1(0,1)$ we have
$$
\int_0^1(u')^2(x)\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\pi^2a_k^2(u)\ge \pi^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2(u)=\pi^2\int_0^1u^2(x)\,dx,
$$
i.e.
$$
\int_0^1u^2(x)\,dx\le \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^1(u')^2(x)\,dx \quad \forall\ u \in H_0^1(0,1).
$$
**Remark** The constant $m=\frac{1}{\pi^2}$ is optimal, and 
$$
\int_0^1u^2(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^1(u')^2(x)\,dx \iff u(x)=a\sin(\pi x), \ a \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 6):

Since $f(0)=0$, 
$$|f(x)|=|\int_0^xf'(t)dt|\le \int_0^x|f'(t)|dt\le\int_0^1|f'(t)|dt .$$
Then by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$(f(x))^2\le  (\int_0^1|f'(t)|dt)^2\le \int_0^1(f'(t))^2dt.$$
Integrating both sides of the inequality above over $[0,1]$, it follows that

$$\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx\le  \int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx.$$

Therefore, $\delta=1$ works, but it is far from the optimal choice of $\delta$.

Comment: if you integrate both side of $(f(x))^2\le  (\int_0^1|f'(t)|dt)^2\le \int_0^1(f'(t))^2dt$ it follow that $\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx\le  \iint_0^1(f'(x))^2dx.$ and why ?($\iint_0^1(f'(x))^2dx\le\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx$

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: The right hand side is $\int_0^1(\int_0^1(f'(t))^2dt)dx=\int_0^1(f'(t))^2dt=\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx.$

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo The right-hand side is constant.

Comment: matematico chibchas:sorry  why its constant ?

Comment: *Therefore, $δ=1$ works, but it is far from the optimal choice of $δ$.* Indeed, the optimal choice $\delta=(2\pi)^{-2}$ is given by Wirtinger's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions