# Prove $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^2\,dx\le\int_{0}^{1}|f{'}(x)|^2\,dx$ with $f(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

> Let $f$ has following properties:
>   1)f has continuous derivative in$[0,1]$; 2)$f(0)=0$; then proof $$\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^2\,dx\le\int_{0}^{1}|f{'}(x)|^2\,dx$$

I think the condition "$f(0)=0$"may be used to add $f(0)$ or $f^2(0)$ in any place. And then maybe I can use the *Lagrange Mean Value Theorem* to substitude $f(x)-f(0) $with the $f{'}(\theta)x$. But I can't proof it. So How can I do with this problem? thank you.

By the way, a question that has been asked is quite similar to it: [just this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412052/prove-this-int-02f2xdx-le-int-02f2xdx)

Comment: Note that you can remove the Absolute value, due to the square. Which tool can you use?

Comment: Look at the second answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282095/prove-that-there-is-a-delta-such-that-int-01-fx2dx-leq-delta-i

Comment: The other question is quite similar to it is[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282095/prove-that-there-is-a-delta-such-that-int-01-fx2dx-leq-delta-i.se]. But there is still different because the other has an *additional* condition "$f(1)=0$. But the second answer under that question doesn't use this condition while still solve that problem with a not accurate and optimal solution. That method can also be used to solve my question just similar to the following answer under my question. (just have a little difference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact we have  a better inequality: $\int_0^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx =\int_0^{1}|\int_0^{x} f'(t)dt|^{2}dx\leq \int_0^{1} \int_0^{x} |f'(t)|^{2}dt xdx \leq \frac  1 2\int_0^{1} |f'(t)|^{2}dt $.

I have used Cauchy - Schwarz inequality and the fact that $\int_0^{x}|f'(t)|^{2}dt \leq \int_0^{1}|f'(t)|^{2}dt$.

Comment: How do you get the inequality in the middle? Where the square moves into the integral?

Comment: @Thomas I have added an explanation. Is it clear now? I am writing $f'$ as $(1)(f')$ and applying C-S inequality.

Comment: You can use Fubini to actually get $$\int_0^1|f(x)|^2 dx\leq \int_0^1|f'(t)|^2(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t^2}{2})dt$$

Comment: @Kavi.Second line. You have ,,,,(dt)x(dx).Where does the x come from? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas It is $\int_0^{x} 1^{2}dt$. I am applying C-S inequality to the product of $1$ and $f'$.

Comment: Kavi.Thanks, finally got it.

Comment: So what $f(x)$ would be like when the equality holds?