# How do I prove $\int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^{2} ~\operatorname{d}x \leq \int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^{2} ~\operatorname{d}x$ in functional analysis?

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that if $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)\in C^1[0,1]$, then
$$ \int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^{2} ~\operatorname{d}x \leq \int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^{2} ~\operatorname{d}x $$
I tried applying integration by parts and generated $\int (f'(x))^{2} ~\operatorname{d}x$ on other side but i cant prove the inequality, or is by parts not the correct approach?

Comment: Try tu use the fundamental theorem of Calculus along with Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282133) answer, which I found with [this](https://approach0.xyz/search) highly recommended website.

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular case of [Poincaré's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality):

Let $x \in [0,1]$ we have: $\displaystyle f(x)=f(0) + \int_0^x f^{\prime}(t)dt=\int_0^x f^{\prime}(t)dt $,  it follows that:
\begin{align}
    |f(x)| & \leq \int_0^x |f^{\prime}(t)|dt \\
    & \leq \int_0^1 |f^{\prime}(t)|dt \\
    & \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f^{\prime}(t)|^2dt} \sqrt{\int_0^1 1^2dt} \, \, \text{  (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)}\\
    |f(x)| & \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f^{\prime}(t)|^2dt}
\end{align}

Squaring the latter inequality we get : $\displaystyle f(x)^2  \leq \int_0^1 |f^{\prime}(t)|^2dt$, integrating over $[0,1]$

$$\int_0^1 f(x)^2  \leq \int_0^1 f^{\prime}(t)^2dt$$